Are variable capacitors compatible with breadboards still available?
Variable capacitors are used less, since the preference is for digital adjustment.  And through hole parts are used for less, since the preference is for SMD. Finally, many variable capacitors have leads too large to fit into breadboards.
Consequently, I'm having trouble finding any variable capacitors that can fit into breadboards.  Are such a thing still available? How can I identify them? If not, what are good alternatives?

Were variable capacitors compatible with breadboards EVER available? The parasitic capacitance of breadboards is not really compatible with the kinds of RF designs in which such capacitors would be used.


Variable capacitors are used less, since the preference is for digital adjustment.


I see variable capacitors all over the place. How do you think VCOs are tuned? They're usually electronically controlled variable capacitors, implemented as PIN diodes, FET barriers, or other voltage-controlled capacitance approaches.
If we're talking mechanically adjusted variable capacitors: yes of course these are rarely used. They're terrible! Tiny capacitance! Huge uncertainty! You need a motor or a human to adjust them! You can't control them at any relevant control loop bandwidth! They're useless to modern applications.
What I still see in low-cost electronics that have been made unmodifiedly for ~ 40 years or more is trimmers, used for factory frequency calibrarions. But they're not used there because that's the technologically advantageous solution – it's the "I have bought 100 million of these and they were really cheap, also who cares if we're off by 5%?" solution that makes no sense to small series or single-device users, usually.

And through hole parts are used for less, since the preference is for SMD

Less about preference but about suitability: can't use through-hole components for high frequencies.

Finally, many variable capacitors have leads too large to fit into breadboards.

ah, so we are talking about mechanically adjusted variable capacitors, probably of the air-gap kind.
Yeah, a device that you have to turn by hand plugged into a solderless bread board: that's a flaky contact happening, right there. So, I'd say, if you're using soldered breadboard, drill out the holes you need, or design your own quick PCB for the purpose of holding your tuning circuitry (it makes a lot of sense to not have the parasitic inductance of a solder trace, or much worse even, of a solderless breadboard row, between your variable capacitor and whatever it is used to control).

Are such a thing still available? How can I identify them?

Sure, digikey alone lists hundreds of them as "normally stocking". Some are certainly through-hole. Note that shopping questions are off-topic here.

If not, what are good alternatives?

Design your system such that whatever you want to control with a mechanically adjusted variable capacitor is done in a different way, I'd say.

You can purchase adapter boards that have 0.1" spaced holes for headers and SMT pads. It should not be too difficult to fit an SMT variable capacitor onto such a board, for example one designed to accept 0805 passive parts.
Solderless breadboards have a lot of stray capacitance, at least several pF typically, so they are far from ideal in constructing circuits that operate at frequencies where a small SMT variable capacitor might be used.
You can still find film type through-hole variable capacitors and simply extend the leads by soldering some bare wire onto them, and bend them to fit. Digikey lists about a dozen that are relatively affordable and in stock.
